# How to get latest post from threads with several fields?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Laravel 5.8/mysql5 app I get latest post from threads like

```
$forumThreads= ForumThread
    ::getByForumId($forum_id)
    ->select(
        'forum_threads.*',
        \DB::raw(' ( select count('.$prefix.'forum_posts.id) from '.$prefix.'forum_posts where '.$prefix.'forum_posts.forum_thread_id = '.$prefix.'forum_threads.id ) as forum_posts_count'),
        \DB::raw(' ( select created_at from '.$prefix.'forum_posts where '.$prefix.'forum_posts.forum_thread_id = '.$prefix.'forum_threads.id  order by id desc limit 1) as latest_post_created_at')
    )
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($forum_threads_per_page)
    ->get();
```

It works ok, but I need to get several fields for latest post. If I change condition as :

```
\DB::raw(' ( select created_at, title, slug from '.$prefix.'forum_posts where
```

I got error :

```
Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Of there is a way ?

**modified block:** 
In app/ForumThread.php I created

```
  public function latestForumPost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ForumPost')->latest();
    }

    public function forumPosts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ForumPost');

    }
```

and in my control I make :

```
  $forumThreads= ForumThread::with('latestForumPost')->withCount('forumPosts')
                              ->getByForumId($forum_id)
                              ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
                              ->offset($limit_start)
                              ->take($forum_threads_per_page)
                              ->get();

    foreach( $forumThreads as $next_key=>$nextForumThread ) {
        $nextForumThread->latest_post_created_at= $nextForumThread->latestForumPost->created_at;
    }
```

and that works!
But when I try to use $nextForumThread->latestForumPost in my blade.php file :

```
<tr v-for="nextForumThread, index in forumThreads" :key="nextForumThread.id">
    nextForumThread.latestForumPost::{{ nextForumThread.latestForumPost}}
```

Itdoes not work.  Can it be use in blade template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a simple relationship.

```
// ForumThread model
public function latestPost()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Post')->latest();
}

public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

Now we will use `latestPost` relationship to get details of latest post per category and `posts` to get count.

So your refactored query would be:

```
$forumThreads= ForumThread::with('latestPost')->withCount('posts')
    ->getByForumId($forum_id)
    ->orderBy($order_by, $order_direction)
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($forum_threads_per_page)
    ->get();
```

You can access these data as follow:

```
foreach ($forumThreads as $thread) {
    echo $thread->posts_count;    -- to show posts counts per thread.
    echo $thread->latestPost->id;  -- to access any field from latestPost
}
```

Reference:

[Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

[Tweaking Laravel Relationship](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/)

Comment: Did you ever test this? What SQL query will be generated for eager loading `latestPost`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
Please look at modified block:

Comment: If you are converting it into array. You can access same by `latest_forum_post`. Try and let me know.

Comment: The convention is simple: camelCase for relations. Otherwise dynamic properties won't work for you.

Thing is, when using `toArray/toJson`, relations keys are changed to snake_case.